# CSS - Show background image above div

Tags: html, css, styles, background-image

I have a component which creates some shape having a hole inside it, the component has a solid background and I would like the hole to show the background image below it (so it looks like an actual hole).

The markdown would be something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="component">
    <div class="hole"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the styles:

```
body {
  background-image: url(some-image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.component {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.component .hole {
  background: transparent !important; // not sure
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
```

Can it be done? Is there some workaround for it?

EDIT

As requested, you may find the component [here](http://recuen.co)

The dogtag has a solid background and the hole above it should show the background below.

You may find as well the code in [my repo](http://github.com/RecuencoJones/recuen.co): [body styles](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/recuen.co/blob/develop/app/styles/styles.scss#L7), [dogtag styles](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/recuen.co/blob/develop/app/styles/dogtag.scss), [home markup](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/recuen.co/blob/develop/app/views/home/home.tpl.html) and [dogtag markup](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/recuen.co/blob/develop/app/components/dogtag/dogtag.tpl.html).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that i understand what you mean 
but there is a feature opacity:0.8; the value is between 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: But adding opacity to .component won't make its background solid, right? I can try tho

Answer (score 0):

i visualy still had no idea what are you trying to accomplish., you can add the live demo just to be more clear...

but if you want to use transparent background, maybe you can use this in stylesheet:

```
.hole{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Added links to demo and repo for clarification, will add actual snippets later (sorry, I'm on mobile rn)

Comment: the .hole background cant go throught the element bacground  below.core ...,  you can make vew another object to fill the grey to form the shape that you want without touching the .hole zone

Comment: or you could eyedropping the same color as sky color in the body bcground for the .hole and use a little gradient for the trick maybe.... or you could use HTML canvas createImageData() Method to make in image per pixel(but ithink thats very hard)....and for the easy way, why dont you use image file? seriously, you could just create the shape on the photoshop in like minute...just saying :).

Comment: Hahaha, sure I could, but I'm really bad with photoshop and in Gimp or Illustrator it would take me some time, actually I feel much more confortable with CSS, plus wanted to test myself.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<style>

        #box {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background: url("photos/bamboo.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            border: 10px solid red;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="box"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: I guess I can place the same background for the body and the hole, and pray for them to line up. Just tried and kinda works, but sometimes it just doesn't fit and both images get misaligned.

Comment: sorry i did not understand that..give me some code if you want

Comment: Just added code, repo and actual demo to the question!

Answer (score -1):

it cannot be done that way. beacuse your html page dosent underatand it... but you can do the HTML page like this.

```
   <div="hole">
```

Comment: Well yeah, I didn't write the whole HTML markdown, just the important parts hahaha